# can I use multiple variables in one j2 line?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

My Ansible playbook fails when I add a 2nd variable to the j2 template.
I am trying to code for static route statements in a Cisco router.
If my j2 lines looks like this:

```
{% for vrf in json_data['vrf_routes'] %}
ip route {{  vrf.prefix  }}
{% endfor %}
```

The playbook works. If I add the rest of what I need to that line:
    ip route {{  vrf.prefix  }}  {{ vrf.next-hop }} name {{ vrf.name }}

The playbook fails. Is this the proper syntax for handling multiple variables in one j2 line?

Comment: yes, you can and your syntax looks right. perhaps the list variable you are iterating in the loop , has elements that dont have the extra keys (`next-hop` and `name`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the hyphen in `next-hop` .. it is being interpreted as a minus operation.

Try this instead:

```
{% for vrf in json_data['vrf_routes'] %}
{{ vrf.prefix }} {{ vrf["next-hop"] }} name {{ vrf.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you that was it. My routes are now formatting correclty in the template with all three variables  in one line.